# what if I would like to disable a particular row from edit, but not show the edit/delete buttons in ng2 smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in my angular6 project. How to disable edit and delete for particular rows in ng2-smart table angular6

Answer (score 1):

Just add the actions.edit and actions.delete table properties to the settings and set them to false, something like below:

```
settings = {
    actions: {
        edit: false,
        delete: false
    }
}
```

You can check out other table properties/configuration [here](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

Comment: I would like to disable the edit and delete button for the first four rows of the table and if I add a new record it should come with edit and delete button

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector` to get the particular element or add a specific class to your edit action to make it easier for you to retrieve the element and apply a class to it. Unfortunately i have no ideas for an easier way to do it.